# Desiging Shellcode gives incorrect results

Tags: c, assembly, shellcode

I made this simple assembly program:

```
.text
    .globl _start
    _start:
        mov %20, %rbx
        mov %1, %rax
        int $0x80
```

This is obviously running on a 64 bit OS (Linux). I then compiled it as follows:

```
as -o ExitShellcode.o ExitShellcode.s
ld -o ExitShellcode ExitShellcode.o
```

And finally after running the program, It exits with a status of 20

```
echo $?
20
```

Using objdump to dump the shellcode for the file gives:

```
objdump -d ExitShellcode

ExitShellcode:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400078 <_start>:
400078: 48 c7 c3 14 00 00 00    mov    $0x14,%rbx
40007f: 48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rax
400086: cd 80                   int    $0x80
```

However, after putting the shellcode in this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char shellcode[] = "\x48\xc7\xc3\x14\x00\x00\x00"
                   "\x48\xc7\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00"
                   "\xcd\x80";

int main()
{
    int *ret;

    ret = (int *)&ret +2;

    *ret = (int)shellcode;

}
```

and compiling:

```
gcc -g -o Shellcode Shellcode.c
Shellcode.c: In function ‘main’:
Shellcode.c:13:9: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different        size     [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
*ret = (int)shellcode;
```

and running, the program exits with a 0 status:

```
echo $?
0
```

What's the proplem? Shouldn't it exit with a 20?

Comment: `*ret = (int)shellcode;`  copies only one int.

Comment: You're never actually calling the shellcode anywhere.

Comment: @slugonamission How do I do it then??

Comment: @wildplasser How do I call the entire shellcode?

Comment: @slugonamission it is supposed to be executed on return from main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code incorrectly assumes that the compiler will put the variable `ret` at a certain place on the stack relative to the return address of `main`. Instead the compiler put it somewhere else, as it is allowed to do, and so your code does nothing. Your probably following a badly designed example you found on the Internet.

If you want to execute the "shellcode" in the `shellcode` array you can try casting to it a pointer to function and then calling it:

```
char shellcode[] = "\x48\xc7\xc3\x14\x00\x00\x00"
               "\x48\xc7\xc0\x01\x00\x00\x00"
               "\xcd\x80";

int main()
{
    ((void (*)()) shellcode)();
}
```

However this will still probably fail because the `.data` section where `shellcode` is placed isn't executable and so the program will crash when run. To fix that problem use the `-zexecstack` option when linking your program. For example:

```
gcc -zexecstack -g -o Shellcode Shellcode.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot; That Worked! But can you explain how does it work?

Comment: @DarkEagle It casts `shellcode` to a pointer to a function and then calls the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help